# Use Win32::Process with Perl of msys git

Tags: windows, git, perl, cpan

I have a [Perl script](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/tests/fsharpqa/testenv/bin/runall.pl), work ok with ActiveState Perl but I am trying to run it with perl.exe bundled with msys git (from Windows command prompt)

I get the following error:

> Can't locate Win32/Process.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at C:\project\tests\fsharpqa\testenv\bin\runall.pl line 3859.

git Perl is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>perl --version
```

> This is perl, v5.8.8 built for msys

Activestate per is:

> This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

I've tried:

1. Download [Win32-Process module](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Process-0.16/Process.pm) from cpan
2. Unzip in a directory `d:\temp\perllib`
3. `Process.pm` exists in `d:\temp\perllib\Win32`
4. Add directory `/d/temp/perllib` to `PERL5LIB` env var

But no luck, I get:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>.\perl.exe -e 'use Win32::Process;'
```

> Can't locate loadable object for module Win32::Process in @INC (@INC contains: /d/temp/perllib /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at -e line 1

With wrong directory in `PERL5LIB` I get instead:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>.\perl.exe -e 'use Win32::Process;'
```

> Can't locate Win32/Process.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /d/temp/perllib2 /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at -e line 1.

Comment: *Please* think of the Perl that comes with MSys-Git as a library for Git only.  Don't ever *Intentionally* use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to *install* the module. You can't just copy the contents of the distribution into your include path.

Take a look at [`perldoc perlmodinstall`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html).

Comment: This may be harder than it looks... msys perl told me "OS unsupported" when I tried it. Apparently msys is treated as a separate platform, like cygwin, but it's not as well supported as cygwin.

Comment: tried to install, commented "os unsupported" for try it, but i cannot nmake it 

    ```NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys/Config.pm'
    Stop.```

Comment: `msys` is a unix emulation environment. You need to use a `make` that's part of that environment (not `nmake`). You'll have other problems installing a Windows-based module in a smulated unix environment (though it is possible given that you are actually on a Windows platform). But why oh why are you using ancient limited `msys`? You mention you have ActivePerl installed. Why not use that?

Comment: i am trying to run it on http://www.appveyor.com/ ( an hosted ci server) where activeperl is not installed ( too much time to download+install )

i have activestate perl installed my machine , but i cannot install it on server (where perl script should run)
On that server i have git ( so perl bundled with it ) and i was trying to run it anyway, but maybe is not possible